# Error Number: 1064 CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, mysql-error-1064

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'png WHERE `Id` = '5'' at line 1

```
UPDATE `photos` SET `PhotoName` = screencapture-localhost-quickstart_shopy-1508597579405.png WHERE `Id` = '5'
```

Filename: C:\xampp1\htdocs\ams\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

**Model_File**

```
public function EditPhoto1($data,$Id)
{
    $this->db->where('Id', $Id);
    $this->db->set('PhotoName', $data['PhotoName'], FALSE);
    return $this->db->update('photos');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
public function EditPhoto1($data,$Id)
{
    $photoName = $data['PhotoName'];
    $this->db->where('Id', $Id);
    $this->db->set('PhotoName',$photoName);
    return $this->db->update('photos');

}
```

Comment: That query is generated via code. You need to correct the PHP Code that is generating this query.

Comment: again error

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'png WHERE `Id` = '5'' at line 1

UPDATE `photos` SET `PhotoName` = screencapture-localhost-quickstart_shopy-1508597579405.png WHERE `Id` = '5'

Filename: C:\xampp1\htdocs\ams\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: Please help me 
In this Code

Comment: ohk wait a minute

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks
You are a hero

Comment: pleasure bro pls accept this answer and also do upvote it :)

Comment: click on the right icon appearing below answer and click on the up arrow on answer to upvote check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function EditPhoto1($data,$Id)
{
    $this->db->where('Id', $Id);
    $d = ['PhotoName' => $data['PhotoName']];
    $this->db->update('photos', $d); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove **False** from set method.

```
public function EditPhoto1($data,$Id)
{
    $this->db->where('Id', $Id);
    $this->db->set('PhotoName', (strval)$data['PhotoName']);
    return $this->db->update('photos');
}
```